# In Activiti, how do I check if a variable is set?

Tags: java, workflow, activiti

For example I have a workflow which can start immediately or with a delay (`startTime` variable).

Right after the `startEvent` I have an `exclusiveGateway` where I check if the flow should go on or wait until `startTime`.

```
<exclusiveGateway id="startGateway" default="startSequenceFlow3"/>
<sequenceFlow id="startSequenceFlow1" sourceRef="startGateway" targetRef="startTimer">
    <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${startTime != null}]]></conditionExpression>
</sequenceFlow>
```

Starting the workflow passing a variable `startTime` works fine, but passing no `startTime` throws an exception:

> Cannot resolve identifier 'startTime'

What would be the best way to check if `startTime` is set, since `startTime != null` is not working? I would prefer not to pass a `startTime` at all (not `startTime=null`).

Code that I use including the variable:

```
variables.put("startTime", startTime);
ProcessInstance instance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(processKey, variables);
```

or without:

```
ProcessInstance instance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(processKey, variables);
```

Comment: Instead of not setting `startTime` at all, you could set it to a special value, for example `NONE`, and then check in the process if it's set to `NONE` to decide what to do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```
${execution.getVariable('startTime') != null}
```

Comment: IMO this is the best answer.

Comment: There is also a method `execution.hasVariable('startTime')` available.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set **startTime** variable in both cases;

```
variables.put("startTime", startTime);
ProcessInstance instance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(processKey, variables);
```

and

```
variables.put("startTime", null);
ProcessInstance instance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(processKey, variables);
```

Then check variable in gateway

```
<exclusiveGateway id="startGateway" default="waitSequenceFlow"/>
<sequenceFlow id="startSequenceFlow" sourceRef="startGateway" targetRef="firstTask">
    <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${empty startTime}]]></conditionExpression>
</sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="waitSequenceFlow" sourceRef="startGateway" targetRef="startTimer"/>
```

**OR**

You can use http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnTimerStartEvent

Comment: Yes I know that I can set the variable to `null`. I would prefer to have a method where I do not have to set the variable. For example I have two GUIs and each of them fills in only the variables it provides, meaning that in GUI1 are different variables than in GUI2. I upvoted, but can't mark it as answer.

Comment: You can add ServiceTask before Gateway, which check if variable is set and if not, then set it with null.